# Configuración del componente daterangepicker

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

Obtengo las fechas de la base de datos en formato YYYY-MM-DD y las Inicializo en JQuery en formato DD-MM-YYYY

```
$('#dateRange').daterangepicker({
    "startDate": $("#start").val(),
    "endDate": $("#end").val(),
}, function(start, end, label) {
    $("#start").val(start.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
    $("#end").val(end.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
});
```

y lo presenta como MM-DD-YYYY

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito configurar el daterangepicker con el formato DD-MM-YYYY, en Español y con las opciones de personalizar los rangos de fecha como en la imagen de abajo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por su orientación.

Answer (score 0):

Esto lo puedes hacer con la opción de locale en el constructor de daterangepicker:

```js
$('selector').daterangepicker({
  ...
  locale: {
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
  } 
})
```

Comment: Que bien @Camilo Gomez ya lo configure, me sale en español pero no toma el formato DD-MM-YYYY